# No Matching Function for call GetLine()

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, istream

I am attempting to create a function in C++ that reads all lines from a file, then concatenates all of the lines into a single string, then returns the string. Here is the code I am using to accomplish this:

```
// at the top of the file

#include "string_helper.hpp" // contains definition for function
#include <vector>
#include <string.h> // used in another function within the same file
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// the code I believe to be problematic

ifstream input("file.txt");
string result(0);
string line;

while (std::getline(&input,&line)) {
    result += line;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this code, however, I receive this error:

```
<project root>/src/string_helper.cpp:52:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream (*)(std::__cxx11::string), std::__cxx11::string*)’
   while (std::getline(&input,&line)) {
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6.3.1/string:53:0,
                 from include/string_helper.hpp:22,
                 from <project root>/src/string_helper.cpp:19:
```

I looked at www.cplusplus.com, and it listed the definition of getline as:

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
```

I am confused, because I am using the & symbol in the declaration of the while loop, but the compiler still says that I am using the incorrect arguments.

Edit: It turns out I accidentally created a function. The real declaraction for `input` was:

```
ifstream input(string(filename));
```

Because I had to parse `filename` from a `char *`. I did not include this in the original code, because I was trying to make it generic so it would apply to many people. I am relatively new to C++. Simply creating the string outside of the declaration of `input` fixed the problem. So I did:

```
string fname(filename);
ifstream input(fname);
```

I am sorry.

Comment: `&` means different things when used in different places. A good C++ book would cover that.

Comment: The code and error message don't match -- unless you're hitting the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), or have a function called `input`. The error message indicates that the first argument you are passing is a function pointer.

Answer (score 3):

GetLine's parameters are references. In C++, you do not need to explicitly give a function a reference. The compiler will do that for you.

Therefore, your function call:

```
std::getline(&input,&line)
```

will become:

```
std::getline(input, line)
```

Comment: While this is the right answer, I expect OP to come back saying that it doesn't fix the problem, because of the error message content `getline(std::ifstream (*)(std::__cxx11::string), std::__cxx11::string*)` which indicates that the first argument being passed is a function pointer, not a pointer-to-ifstream. There is likely a most-vexing-parse (or simple typo) hiding in OP's real code.

Comment: This does not work. I get a similar error, that is like the above error though without the *'s at the end of the types.

Comment: cdhowie: The real code has the following in it: ifstream input(string(filename)); because it needs to parse the filename from a pointer to a character.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the **addresses** of your variables. Somewhat confusingly for a beginner `&` means reference in the context of a variable type but means address of in the context of using a variable.

for that call to work [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) would need to accept pointer arguments, which it does not and so there is no matching function call, given the arguments provided.

You don't have to do anything special to pass a reference. The distinction between a reference and a value being passed to a function is made by the function and not the caller.

So just remove those ampersands and it will work ok.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input("file.txt");
    string result;
    string line;

    while (getline(input, line)) 
    {
        result += line;
    }

    cout << result << '\n';
}
```

You also don't need to initialise the `result` string. It is initialised to an empty string by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that your `std::getline(...)` is using the correct type of variables as its parameters.

1. - `std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input`
   - `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str`
   - `CharT delim`
2. - `std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>&& input`
   - `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str`
   - `CharT delim`
3. - `std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input`
   - `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str`
4. - `std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input`
   - `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str`
   - `CharT delim`

You should be able to just change your parameters from their referenced addresses (`&`) to their actual value (no `&`). When a function asks for a `&value`, you can just pass it the value directly, typically.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("C:\\temp\\file.txt");
    std::string result;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(input, line)) {
        result += line;
    }
    printf("Made it!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Attempting this gives me several errors about how "CharT", "Traits" and "Allactor" do not exist.

Comment: Thanks, @CMan22! Can you do me a favor? Can you copy my updated code snippet and re-build as it's written? I just want to make sure it's precisely _this_ code causing errors. If it is still broken, could you tell me which C++ you're using? E.g., GCC, Clang, Visual C++, etc.

Comment: Okay @CMan22, one last little update. I had to change `result`'s initializer for it to be compatible for Clang and GCC. Here's a site where I was testing compilation: http://rextester.com/HXSUDT66780

Answer (score 0):

Put this code. It will work temporarily you can make it generic.

```
//#include "string_helper.hpp" // contains definition for function
#include <vector>
#include <string.h> // used in another function within the same file
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream input("file.txt");
    string result;
    char line[100];


    while (input.getline(line,'\n')) 
    {
        result += line;
    }
    cout<<"string = "<<result<<endl;
}
```